# Xcode .pch error while compiling. clang file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, pch

I have a very annoying problem.
I backed up my code on Dropbox but now i get this error while compiling

> clang: error: no such file or directory: '../firstFoo-Prefix.pch'

Since the only .pch file in my project in Xcode and my project folder is secondFoo-Prefix.pch and I don't know how to fix this error I've decided to remove every .pch file so i went into Project> Build Settings and removed everything in the Prefix Header and set Precompile Prefix Header to NO.

Before this the Prefix Header had value secondFoo-Prefix.pch and not firstFoo-Prefix.pch.
Even though the compiler should not look for .pch files I still get that error.
I've looked everywhere in my project but I can't seem to find anywhere firstFoo-Prefix.pch.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can occur (not your fault) when the Xcode project file database gets messed up such that the referenced file does not appear in the navigation area but is still somehow included in one of the various list of files used for the build phases.

To see if this is the case:

- In the Finder, right click on the project file and select 'Show Package Contents'
- Right click on the file 'project.pbxproj' and 'Open With->TextEdit.app'
- In TextEdit menu: 'Edit->Find->Find...' [or command-F] then enter '.pch'
- Look at all occurrences of '.pch' [command -G to move to next one]

If you find occurrences of '../firstFoo-Prefix.pch' then your project file is corrupted. Looking at the context of the occurrence(s) will give you some indication of which area the corruption occurs in (e.g. build phase compile files list).

Sometimes just deleting those references (after having backed-up the project file of course) has worked for us but other times it just makes matters worse. The safest recovery is to create a new project file and copy over all the folder groups and settings manually. Your source code is all fine, it's just the cross-references and build settings that need reworking.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve it by recreating the project and copying the source code. Before this I tried editing the project.pbxproj file but I got a linker error.

Comment: git deintegrate, git install helped with my problem, after xcode update

Answer (score 2):

Do a clean for build using this combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have Framework which need to add to main project from derived data after it building successful. So copy items if needed was not tick marked and that's why giving error and also @ZAZ and @chiwangc mentioned cleaned it before building.[image]